# How to optimise RadComboBox clearItems function

Tags: javascript, jquery, telerik, telerik-combobox

I have a MultiSelectDropDown, that is, several `RadComboBox` controls are used in a combined way. For example, I can have a dropdown for regions, another for depots and another for user. The idea is to change the content of lower levels dynamically whenever items are selected or unselected on a higher level. The problem is that in the case when many items are selected, this becomes brutally slow due to some Telerik `functions`, but I do not understand why. This is a chunk from the client-side of the MultiSelectDropDown prototype:

```
changeLowerLevels: function (valueIndex, values, value) {
    if (!this.canChange) return;
    //Get selected values from combobox
    var combo = $find(this.ddlIDs[valueIndex - 1]);
    var cbItems = combo.get_checkedItems();
    var selectedItems = [];
    var change = null;
    var counter = 0;
    if (cbItems.length) this.filterString = "";
    for (var i = 0; i < cbItems.length; i++) {
        counter++;
        if (this.filterString == "") this.filterString = cbItems[i].get_text();
        selectedItems.push(cbItems[i].get_value());
    }
    if (counter > 1) this.filterString += " with " + (counter - 1) + " other" + ((counter > 2) ? "s" : "");
    if (JSON.stringify(selectedItems) === JSON.stringify(this.selectedItems[valueIndex - 1]) || selectedItems == [])
        return;
    this.selectedItems[valueIndex - 1] = selectedItems;

    var controlObject = this;
    var combo = $find(this.ddlIDs[valueIndex]);
    var comboItems = combo.get_items();
    if(!this.disabled) combo.enable();
    combo.clearItems();

    if (valueIndex == 1) this.twoLevelCache = values;
    var val = values;

    //break if all items are found
    var nrOfSelectedItems = this.selectedItems[valueIndex - 1].length;
    var nrOfFoundItems = 0;
    var index = 0;
    var indexes = [];
    var found = false;
    while (nrOfFoundItems < nrOfSelectedItems && val[index] !== undefined) {
        found = (this.selectedItems[valueIndex - 1].indexOf(val[index].Value) != -1);
        if (!(found))
            index++;
        else {
            indexes.push(index)
            nrOfFoundItems++;
            index++;
        }
    }

    //separators from valuesIndex - 1 level
    var controlObject = this;
    for (var i = 0; i < indexes.length; i++) {
        var separator = new Telerik.Web.UI.RadComboBoxItem();
        separator.set_text("<span><a class=\"checkAll tt-multi-uncheck-icon\" index=\"" + index + "\">U</a>" + $find(this.ddlIDs[valueIndex - 1]).findItemByValue(val[indexes[i]].Value).get_text() + "</span>");
        separator.set_value("");
        separator.set_isSeparator(true);
        comboItems.add(separator);
        this.twoLevelCache.push(val[indexes[i]].Levels);

        //valuesIndex level
        var valuesArray = val;
        var comboItem = new Telerik.Web.UI.RadComboBoxItem();
        for (var depot in valuesArray[indexes[i]].Levels) {
            comboItem = new Telerik.Web.UI.RadComboBoxItem();
            comboItem.set_text(valuesArray[indexes[i]].Levels[depot].Name);
            comboItem.set_value(valuesArray[indexes[i]].Levels[depot].Value);
            comboItems.add(comboItem);
            comboItem = null;
        }

        $('#' + this.ddlIDs[valueIndex] + '_DropDown a.checkAll').unbind().on("click", function () {
            checkAllLowerItems(this, controlObject.ddlIDs[valueIndex]);
        });
    }
    combo.set_emptyMessage(this.allText);
    //$("#" + this.ddlIDs[valueIndex]).html(returnValue);
    if (this.ddlIDs.length > valueIndex + 1) {
        var paramToPass = (((val == undefined) || (val[index] === undefined)) ? ("") : (val[index]));
        if (this.allText.length > 0)
            this.changeLowerLevels(valueIndex + 1, paramToPass, "");
        else {
            if (paramToPass !== "")
                paramToPass = paramToPass.Levels;
            if ((val[index] == undefined) || (val[index].Levels[0] === undefined) || (val[index].Levels[0].Value === "")) {
                this.changeLowerLevels(valueIndex + 1, paramToPass, "");
            }
            else {
                this.changeLowerLevels(valueIndex + 1, paramToPass, val[index].Levels[0].Value);
            }
        }
    }
    else {
        if (this.allText.length > 0)
            this.selectedItems[valueIndex] = "";
        else
            if ((val[index] == undefined) || (val[index].Levels[0] === undefined) || (val[index].Levels[0].Value === "")) {
                this.selectedItems[valueIndex] = "";
            }
            else {
                this.selectedItems[valueIndex] = val[index].Levels[0].Value;
            }
    }

    this.setText();
}
```

`combo.clearItems()` is extremeley slow. I have take a look on how it is implemented:

```
function (){var f=this._parent._getControl();?if(f._checkBoxes){f._checkedIndicesJson="[]";?f._checkedIndices=[];?var g=f.get_items();?for(var d=0,e=g.get_count();?d<e;?d++){var c=f.get_items().getItem(d);?c.set_checked(false);?}f.updateClientState();?}a.RadComboBoxItemCollection.callBaseMethod(this,"clear");?}
```

How can I make sure that this Javascript function speeds up?

Comment: I've recently done very similar thing - 3 combos with hierarchical data, thus selected item in the first one determines the content of the 2nd one and so on. Is there a reason why You can't do it with a server-side data  binding? Adding a parameter to the data source of the 2nd combo which will be the `SelectedValue` of the 1st one. Then You can simply call `DataBind` on the 2nd one in the `OnSelectedIndexChanged` event of the 1st one.

Comment: @Skipper I can do it with server-side data binding, in fact, this is how it worked previously. However, this was changed a while ago and we seek to fix this. However, I was able to optimize this by rewriting some Telerik functionalities on Monday. I will write an answer about this here in the not too far-fetched future.

Comment: @Skipper I have written the answer I have promised you. I hope it helps you if you find a similar problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have finally solved the problem by rewriting Telerik client-side functionalities. It was a long and difficult debugging, but it yielded a large performance boost in the most difficult circumstances. From ~30 000 milliseconds, to ~300. Let's see the parts of the optimization:

1. **The actual rewrite**

`/* Overriding Telerik functions Start */
    var overridenTelerikControls = false;
    function overrideTelerikFunctionalities() {
        if (!overridenTelerikControls) {
            overridenTelerikControls = true;
            Telerik.Web.UI.RadComboBox.prototype.clearItems = function (isMultiSelectDropDown) { 
                this.get_items().clear(isMultiSelectDropDown); 
                this._itemData = null; 
            };
            Telerik.Web.UI.RadComboBoxItemCollection.prototype.clear = function (isMultiSelectDropDown){
                var f=this._parent._getControl();
                if(f._checkBoxes){
                    f._checkedIndicesJson="[]";
                    f._checkedIndices=[];
                    var g = f.get_items();
                    for(var d=0,e=g.get_count();d<e;d++){
                        var c=f.get_items().getItem(d);
                        c.set_checked(false, isMultiSelectDropDown);
                    }
                    if (isMultiSelectDropDown) {
                        f._updateComboBoxText();
                        if (f._checkAllCheckBoxElement != null) {
                            f._updateCheckAllState();
                        }
                    }
                    f.updateClientState();
                }
                Telerik.Web.UI.RadComboBoxItemCollection.callBaseMethod(this, "clear");
            };
            Telerik.Web.UI.RadComboBoxItem.prototype.set_checked = function (d, isMultiSelectDropDown){
                if(!this.get_enabled()){
                    return;
                }
                this._setChecked(d);
                var c=this.get_comboBox();
                if(c){
                    if(d){
                        c._registerCheckedIndex(this.get_index());
                    }else{
                        c._unregisterCheckedIndex(this.get_index());
                    }
                    if (!isMultiSelectDropDown) {
                        c._updateComboBoxText();
                    }
                    if((!isMultiSelectDropDown) && (c._checkAllCheckBoxElement!=null)){
                        c._updateCheckAllState();
                    }
                }
            };
        }
    }
    /* Overriding Telerik functions End*/`

My approach was to keep the old way of their working by default, but if an isMultiSelectDropDown parameter is passed, then work in the optimized manners. So we have a switch materialized as a parameter and we can turn it on/off. The main difference was that the old way was to change the label text showing the selected elements each time a checkbox is checked/unchecked. The main improvement was to do this change after all the checkboxes were checked/unchecked. This extremely simple idea was the driving force behind the boost of performance.

2. **Actual usage**

   ```
   overrideTelerikFunctionalities();
   combo.clearItems(true);
   ```

This was the functionalities were overriden if they were not already and the parameter was true, therefore the new approach was chosen.

3. **Test, test, test**